# Read only access to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want this particular policy to restrict all writes, I only want these particular instances to read from the bucket.

This policy seems to allow me to read and write.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1424867341000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKETNAME"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1424867403000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::MYBUCKETNAME/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I only want these particular instances to read from the bucket"? What *instances*? The policy as stated does not allow writes, so what do you mean by "This policy seems to allow me to read and write"? What testing have you done that shows it allows writes? When you say "me", are you making commands using an IAM User that has existing permissions, or are you making anonymous web calls to the bucket?

Comment: I figured out the issue, I had a bucket policy that allowed any instances within my VPC to read/write from the bucket.

Comment: @luckytaxi please write that up as an answer so this question can be closed :)